# How to create grid-connectivity constraint in Minizinc

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I have a grid NxN where each cell can be "water" or "land", and I want to count for each land cell the number of connected land cell. Eventually, it may be okay just to check if 2 land cell are connected or not (in particular, I need it to do a "Nurikabe" solver).

For example, given

```
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
```

where 0 is water and 1 is land, I want to obtain:

```
0 0 0 0 3
2 0 0 3 3
2 0 0 0 0
0 0 2 2 0
```

This is what I have so far:

```
int: L;
int: H;

array[1..L,1..H] of var 0..1: puzzle; %land = 0, water = 1
array[1..L,1..H] of var 0..99: island_sizes;

 function var int: is_connected(int: x1, int: y1, int: x2, int: y2) = %of course this is not correct
       if puzzle[x1,y1] == 1 \/ puzzle[x2,y2] == 1 then 0 else 1
   endif;
   

constraint forall(i in 1..L, j in 1..H)(
    island_sizes[i,j] = sum(x2 in 1..L, y2 in 1..H) (if is_connected(i,j,x2,y2)==1 then 1 else 0 endif)
);
```

I am not very good with Minizinc functions and in particular with recursive one. Is there a way to specify such function in minizinc?

Thank you in advance!